# Using the Psychrometric Chart to calculate volumetric flow rate

Tags: thermodynamics, hvac

> Blockquote
> The inside design conditions for a conditioned space are 20.1°C dry-bulb and 15.2°C     wet-bulb. The air tem- perature increases 10.6°C as it passes through the conditioned   space. The apparatus dew point is ll.9°C. The heat transfer rate is 456 kW. What is most   nearly the volumetric flow rate of the air passing through the space?

i understand that this can be solved by calculating air flow using the temperature difference

> Blockquote
> V = Q̇/(ρ*Cp*∆T)

but how would I go about it if I want to solve it using the psychrometric chart? Should I plot the enthalpy along the horizontal and specific volume?

Comment: find energy deltas of the two states, use dew point for latent heat, use energy to get mass flowrate, chart to to turn to volumetric.